# sanitize folder names before creation

Tags: security, bash, directory, users

How prevent the injection when creating folders with user supplied paths in a unix like system?

Ideally subfolders can be created only in selected or working folder. Although the creation of folder in wrong places is lesser issue than deletion or hacking, and script is unlikely to have  permissions to access system folders.

I think of either restricting symbols to alphanumerical and a punctuation mark few safer symbols such as _-[] and/or using quotes. I am open to using a small script in ruby or python (though I a have rather old version of them in the system)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295135/turn-a-string-into-a-valid-filename